# dynamic conditional code injection into a java file

Tags: java

I have a java file which has a method that has been coded like this

```
public void testMethod() {
ClassA objA = new ClassA("objA");
objA.someMethod();
ClassA objB = new ClassA("objB");
objB.someMethod();
ClassA objC = new ClassA("objC");
objC.someMethod();
}
```

This file has been given to me and I have the liberty of a) changing this file manually and adding code to it b) changing this file automatically using a Java Parser. My aim here is to control the execution of `someMethod()`. For instance, I want to inject a `Configuration` object into the class, which will specify which object's `someMethod()` should be invoked. So, something like this:

```
Configuration config;

public void testMethod() {
ClassA objA = new ClassA("objA");
if(config.shouldExecuteFor(objA))
objA.someMethod();
ClassA objB = new ClassA("objB");
if(config.shouldExecuteFor(objB))
objB.someMethod();
ClassA objC = new ClassA("objC");
if(config.shouldExecuteFor(objC))
objC.someMethod();
}
```

The if conditions that are shown above, could be

- a) manually added by editing the file or
- b) could be auto inserted by parsing the java file using a java parser.
- c) somehow control behavior at runtime?

I am inclined towards (b). I am not sure if I am solving this problem correctly or not, or if there is something that I can do to solve it in a simpler manner by leveraging annotations/aspects (as in 'c' above).

I would appreciate any input in solving this problem.

Comment: If you are choosing (b), How will you recompile your java file dynamically ?

Comment: This isn't an answer, so putting it here, but it seems that you solved your own problem. You pass in a configuration object, and you use that object to determine behaviour. Therefore it seems that you are already using (a). I'd stay away from dynamically recompiling code unless there is no other method of solving a particular problem (although it is relatively trivial with the compiler apis added in Java 6).

Comment: yes, (a) is what is being used, but it is a bruce force method. The code as it is today is generated by an internal tool, so it does the same instantiation and invoking a method on about 100 objects. So, manually adding 'if' statements is tiring. I need to automate this.

Comment: Instead of adding such an amount of boilerplate code, wouldn't you interfere the method/s `someMethod` to perform the desired check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example using Spring AOP with AspectJ. I created a dummy configuration class `MyConfiguration` which simply returns an alternating boolean when calling its `shouldExecuteFor()` method to have some kind of test behavior. The `ConfiguredCallAspect` uses a call pointcut, which only works in Spring AOP when load time weaving is used. That is why I use XML configuration via `applicationContext.xml` and not annotations. The `-Xreweavable` option in `aop.xml` is also important for that, as well as the two `-javaagent` arguments passed to the JVM. This became rather complex but I think it does the job you were asking for.

src/experiments/stackoverflow/aspectj/ClassA.java

```
package experiments.stackoverflow.aspectj;

public class ClassA {

    private String name;

    public ClassA(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void someMethod() {
        System.out.println("someMethod(\"" + name + "\") called on " + this);
    }

}
```

src/experiments/stackoverflow/aspectj/App.java

```
package experiments.stackoverflow.aspectj;

public class App {

    public void run() {
        ClassA object1 = new ClassA("obj1");
        object1.someMethod();
        ClassA object2 = new ClassA("obj2");
        object2.someMethod();
        ClassA object3 = new ClassA("obj3");
        object3.someMethod();
        ClassA object4 = new ClassA("obj4");
        object4.someMethod();
        ClassA object5 = new ClassA("obj5");
        object5.someMethod();
    }

}
```

src/experiments/stackoverflow/aspectj/ConfiguredCallAspect.java

```
package experiments.stackoverflow.aspectj;

import javax.inject.Inject;

import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Configurable;

@Aspect
@Configurable
public class ConfiguredCallAspect {

    private MyConfiguration config;

    public MyConfiguration getConfig() {
        return config;
    }

    @Inject
    public void setConfig(MyConfiguration config) {
        this.config = config;
    }

    /**
     * Pointcut for all calls to ClassA.someMethod().
     */
    @Around("call(* ClassA.someMethod())")
    public void conditionalExecutionOfSomeMethod(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
        System.out.println("Aspect start");
        if (config.shouldExecuteFor(joinPoint.getTarget())) {
            joinPoint.proceed();
        }
        System.out.println("Aspect end");
    }

}
```

src/experiments/stackoverflow/aspectj/Main.java

```
package experiments.stackoverflow.aspectj;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
        context.getBean(App.class).run();
    }

}
```

src/experiments/stackoverflow/aspectj/MyConfiguration.java

```
package experiments.stackoverflow.aspectj;

public class MyConfiguration {

    private boolean executionTrigger = false;

    public boolean shouldExecuteFor(Object anObject) {
        executionTrigger = !executionTrigger;
        System.out.println("should execute " + anObject + "? " + executionTrigger);
        return executionTrigger;
    }

}
```

src/META-INF/aop.xml

```
<!DOCTYPE aspectj PUBLIC
        "-//AspectJ//DTD//EN" "http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/dtd/aspectj.dtd">
<aspectj>
    <weaver
        options="-Xreweavable">
        <include within="experiments.stackoverflow.aspectj..*" />
    </weaver>
    <aspects>
        <aspect name="experiments.stackoverflow.aspectj.ConfiguredCallAspect"/>
    </aspects>
</aspectj>
```

src/applicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd">

   <aop:aspectj-autoproxy proxy-target-class="true"/>
   <context:load-time-weaver />

   <bean id="configuredCallAspect" class="experiments.stackoverflow.aspectj.ConfiguredCallAspect" factory-method="aspectOf">
        <property name="config"><ref bean="config"/></property>
   </bean>
   <bean id="config" class="experiments.stackoverflow.aspectj.MyConfiguration" />
   <bean id="app" class="experiments.stackoverflow.aspectj.App" />

</beans>
```

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>experiments</groupId>
    <artifactId>experiments</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <org.springframework.version>4.2.1.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
        <aspectj.version>1.8.7</aspectj.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-instrument</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
            <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
            <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Start the program using:

```
java -javaagent:<path-to>/aspectjweaver-1.8.7.jar -javaagent:<path-to>/spring-instrument-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar experiments.stackoverflow.aspectj.Main
```

Produced output:

```
Aspect start
should execute experiments.stackoverflow.aspectj.ClassA@a0bf272? true
someMethod("obj1") called on experiments.stackoverflow.aspectj.ClassA@a0bf272
Aspect end
Aspect start
should execute experiments.stackoverflow.aspectj.ClassA@4a89ef44? false
Aspect end
Aspect start
should execute experiments.stackoverflow.aspectj.ClassA@310a7859? true
someMethod("obj3") called on experiments.stackoverflow.aspectj.ClassA@310a7859
Aspect end
Aspect start
should execute experiments.stackoverflow.aspectj.ClassA@1cbc1dde? false
Aspect end
Aspect start
should execute experiments.stackoverflow.aspectj.ClassA@4971f459? true
someMethod("obj5") called on experiments.stackoverflow.aspectj.ClassA@4971f459
Aspect end
```

Comment: sounds very simple. I will try this out.

Comment: I don't think that it's in fact simple. I am still working on a working minimal example...

Comment: Ok, I tried this, modifying the example to my original source code. It doesn't hit the aspect. I see this in the log - [ContextOverridingClassLoader@af004b] warning at com\test\aspects\TestAspect.java::0 no match for this type name: SampleTest [Xlint:invalidAbsoluteTypeName]

Comment: ok, I changed it to absolute package name - like this -  @Before("call(* com.tests.SampleTest.createANewPerson())"). Now the warning is gone. But still doesn't stop inside the aspect.

Comment: What do you mean, "doesn't stop indside the aspect"? Please post your adapted code since it's hard to guess what you have changed...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89301/discussion-between-jay-and-lars-gendner).

Comment: My original code is a bit confidential. Is it required that all my classes are defined as beans and driven by Spring? So for instance, I am trying to intercept a call that is being made to a third party library. So I guess, the aspect code will not execute because this third party code is not related to or injected via Spring?